# os x cat or grep like commands on large files are extremely slow

Tags: macos, terminal, macbook-pro

I have a macbook pro 2015 with an ssd. Doing a cat to a file is incredibly slow like 5 lines per seconds. I removed *.asl files but it's still extremely slow. I can't seem to find posts of people who suffer specifically the same issue. Same grep on a 2gb file takes couple seconds on my much worse linux box yet rmbp2015 with blazingly fast ssd fails?

I can't diagnose the issue to find a solution to begin with.

Comment: This seems unusual. Are the applications on the notebook working as fast as they should be? Or everything's sluggish just as with your cat file>file? Perhaps you'll get better feedback in [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yes they are working pretty fast. I benchmarked the ssd and it works blazingly fast. Yet command line utilities work exhaustingly slow. Other utilities except for grep cat seems to work fine though.

Comment: only the cat and grep though